# webView muestra teclado virtual y no calendario como en la web

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview

Se me presenta el siguiente problema:

He creado un webView que muestra una página web donde existe un formulario. En este formulario web hay un campo que al pinchar sobre el mismo despliega un calendario (para seleccionar una fecha).

Sin embargo, en mi webView, al pinchar sobre ese campo se me despliega el teclado virtual del móvil (para escribir), y no el calendario, que es lo que me interesa que muestre, como en la web.

¿Hay alguna manera de prevenir este efecto y que el webView muestre el contenido original de la web?

Hasta el momento he encontrado algunas posibles soluciones, pero sin resultado. Por ejemplo, en el xml:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Previene que se despliegue el teclado virtual, pero tampoco muestra el calendario.

En el método onCreate():

```
WebSettings webSettings = wvMain.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 wvMain.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 wvMain.loadUrl("https://MIWEB/Formulario");
```

Es decir, activar javaScript, pero no parece funcionar tampoco.

¿Alguna sugerencia sobre este tema? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado!

Al parecer no basta con activar JavaScript en el webView (`webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`)

También es necesario activar el DOM de JavaScript que, por defecto, viene en false en el webView. Para ello se utiliza el método `setDomStorageEnabled()`

La solución quedaría así:

```
WebSettings webSettings = wvMain.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 wvMain.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
 wvMain.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 wvMain.loadUrl("https://MIWEB/Formulario");
```